# Remove “Shared Folder Synchronization” from Microsoft Office 2010

Tags: windows, microsoft-office

Is there a way to remove “Shared Folder Synchronization” context option after having installed Microsoft Office 2010 ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This isn't the only way, but the way I found that works.

Go to App management menu (aka "Programs and Features"), select "Microsoft Office 2010" -> Change. "Add or Remove Features" -> "Continue":

Click on "Microsoft SharePoint Workspace", select "Not Available". Then press Continue and wait for the component to be uninstalled

Comment: Tried this, the right click menu doesn't go away sadly.

Answer (score 0):

1. Type run in the search bar to open Run panel, type **regedit** in it to open Registry Editor.
2. Go to *HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\ {6C467336-8281-4E60-8204-430CED96822D}*
3. Rename or delete the sub key {6C467336-8281-4E60-8204-430CED96822D}.
   It's recommended to rename it like **backup.{6C467336-8281-4E60-8204-430CED96822D}** instead of deletion as it helps to revert the changes easily.
4. Close Registry Editor then have a check.